# How does this condition hold

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following function which is part of the Trie structure implementation:

```
int alpha_char_strlen (const AlphaChar *str) {
    const AlphaChar *p;
    for (p = str; *p; p++) ;
    return p - str;
```

}

Can any one help me and explain how does the condition for the for loop hold, and precisely what is the condition in this case?
Note: AlphaChar is simply a typedef with unsigned int type and the function counts the AlphaChar characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The condition `*p` is identical to `*p != 0` (if `*p` is of a primitive type). That is, you keep incrementing the pointer `p` until it points to a zero. In other words, you treat `str` as the pointer to a zero-terminated array.

Comment: Pedantically it compares as boolean not integral. More or less the same.

Comment: This answer is only correct if `AlphaChar` resolves to a numeric or pointer type.  If it resolves to a class, then any number of things might happen: the result of `operator void *()` or `operator bool()` or [`operator unspecified_bool_type()`](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) might be tested.  Ultimately, *something* is going to get tested, but it's a bit more complicated than just `*p != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is `*p`, which is short for `*p!=0`.

So it simply scans the AlphaChar array for an occurrence of 0.